# How to fix this XSLT to make it groups XML node exclusively for this attribute combination?

Tags: xml, xslt

Input file:

```
<workorders>
    <workorder>
        <renew id="a">
            <nodeA id="N1">
                <fruit id="1" action="aaa">

                    <orange id="x" action="aa">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Yellow</color>
                            <ada>xxx</ada>
                        </attributes>
                    </orange>

                    <orange id="y" action="change">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Red</color>
                            <year>2012</year>
                        </attributes>
                    </orange>
                    <orange id="x" action="aa">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Pink</color>
                            <ada>xxx</ada>
                        </attributes>
                    </orange>
                    <orange id="y" action="change">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Blue</color>
                            <condition>good</condition>
                        </attributes>
                    </orange>
                </fruit>
            </nodeA>
        </renew>
    </workorder>
</workorders>
```

My Output:

```
<workorders>
    <workorder>
        <renew id="a">
            <nodeA id="N1">
                <fruit id="1" action="aaa">
                    <orange id="x" action="aa">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Pink</color>
                            <ada>xxx</ada>
                        </attributes>
                    </orange>
                    <orange id="y" action="change">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Blue</color>
                            <year>2012</year>
                            <condition>good</condition>
                        </attributes>
                    </orange>
                </fruit>
            </nodeA>
        </renew>
    </workorder>
</workorders>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<workorders>
    <workorder>
        <renew id="a">
            <nodeA id="N1">
                <fruit id="1" action="aaa">
                    <orange id="x" action="aa">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Yellow</color>
                            <ada>xxx</ada>
                        </attributes>
                    </orange>

                    <orange id="x" action="aa">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Pink</color>
                            <ada>xxx</ada>
                        </attributes>
                    </orange>

                    <orange id="y" action="change">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Blue</color>
                            <year>2012</year>
                            <condition>good</condition>
                        </attributes>
                    </orange>
                </fruit>
            </nodeA>
        </renew>
    </workorder>
</workorders>
```

XSL file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:a="http://project.com">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="entity" match="/workorders/*/*/*/*/*" use="concat(parent::*/@id, '_', @id, '_', @action)"/>

    <xsl:function name="a:is-primary" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="ctx"/>
        <!-- need to establish "focus"(context) for the key() function to work -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$ctx">
            <xsl:sequence select="generate-id($ctx) = generate-id(key('entity', concat($ctx/parent::*/@id, '_', $ctx/@id, '_', $ctx/@action))[1])"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:function> 

    <xsl:function name="a:preceded-by" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="ctx"/>
        <xsl:param name="action"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($ctx/preceding::*[a:matches($ctx, ., $action)]) > 0"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="a:followed-by" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="ctx"/>
        <xsl:param name="action"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($ctx/following::*[a:matches($ctx, ., $action)]) > 0"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="a:matches" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="src"/>
        <xsl:param name="target"/>
        <xsl:param name="action"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="
                     ($src/local-name() = $target/local-name()) and
                      ($src/parent::*/@id = $target/parent::*/@id) and 
                      ($src/@id = $target/@id) and 
                      (if ($action = 'same') 
                          then false()
                          else if ($action = 'any')
                              then ($target/@action = $src/@action)
                              else ($target/@action = $action))"/>  
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*/*/*/*[a:is-primary(.)]" priority="1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="attributes" mode="consolidate-most-recent"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="attributes" mode="consolidate-most-recent">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group 
                        select="/workorders/*/*/*/*/*[a:matches(current()/parent::*, ., 'any')]/attributes/*" 
                        group-by="local-name()">
                <!-- take the last in the document order -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[last()]"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*/*/*/*[not(a:is-primary(.))]"/>    
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

What should I add in my xsl file to make the transformation works **only** for node with `action="change"` combination ? right now it groups all of others action combination.

Thanks.

Comment: I recognize your tranform :) in your expected output, don't you expect the `aa` action to show their actual color "attributes" (child elements)? first time it would be Yellow and the second time it would be Pink. I believe you don't want those two to be touched at all, right?

Comment: @PavelVeller Yes your template works well =) I have made slight modification to work with the condition but it couldn't work. You are correct its a typo it shouldn't be touched. should stay the same yellow and pink. Please advise me on the solution. Thanks very much.

Comment: I just have. I am not sure you really wanted those not `@action = 'change'` ordered to appear in front of the consolidated once either.

Comment: @PavelVeller just wondering which part is responsible if I want to make the grouping happens for the same element name only i.e. <orange>? Because there might be another element namely <melon> or <lime> etc. Thanks.

Comment: you would apply changes to those two templates. everything happens there. it flows through the identity transform and then stops at the `a:is-primary()` element where it will consolidate all `attributes`. The other template will silent all nodes that are candidates for merge but are not "primary".

Comment: @PavelVeller I come across a scenario in which the node to be merged doesn't have children i.e <orange id="y" action="change"/> and the output will be merged to become node that has no children which is not how it's supposed to be. Can you point me the trick to accommodate that? I have tried to tweak the solutions but no luck.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this one when a no-`attribute` element is the first one. I didn't test the solution I am about to suggest extensively (so please do!) but I believe it's as easy as changing the `entity` `key` definition to only consider elements with `attribute`s. Like this: `<xsl:key name="entity" match="/workorders/*/*/*/*/*[attributes]" use="...`. The side effect will be that if that no-`attribute` is the only element it won't make it into the result tree. I will post one more comment to explain how you can work around that one

Comment: to make it so that the no-`attributes` node is ignored when it's not the only one in the document and is not ignored if it is the only one you would need to have your key a little more complicated. You would need to add an `or` condition: `<xsl:key name="entity" match="/workorders/*/*/*/*/*[attributes or not(/workorders/*/*/*/*/*[name() = current()/name()][@id = current()/@id][@action = current()/@action][attributes])]" use="...`. I tested and it seems to work. Though I must admit it does look messy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your expected output should actually keep all `@action != 'change'` as-is (that would mean each occurrence will print out the `attributes/*` as in the input document with no attempt to consolidate or merge), you only need to make two small changes:

1) add the `@action = 'change'` to your first "capture" template:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*/*/*/*/*[action = 'change' and a:is-primary(.)]">
```

2) Do the same for your "silent non primary" template:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*/*/*/*/*[@action = 'change' and not(a:is-primary(.))]"/>
```

This will make sure all other nodes go through the identity tranformation template. Running the transform with these two modification on your input document produces:

```
<workorders>
   <workorder>
      <renew id="a">
         <nodeA id="N1">
            <fruit id="1" action="aaa">
               <orange id="x" action="aa">
                  <attributes>
                     <color>Yellow</color>
                     <ada>xxx</ada>
                  </attributes>
               </orange>
               <orange id="y" action="change">
                  <attributes>
                     <color>Blue</color>
                     <year>2012</year>
                     <condition>good</condition>
                  </attributes>
               </orange>
               <orange id="x" action="aa">
                  <attributes>
                     <color>Pink</color>
                     <ada>xxx</ada>
                  </attributes>
               </orange>
            </fruit>
         </nodeA>
      </renew>
   </workorder>
</workorders>
```

p.s. if you wanted the nodes to appear sorted by `@action` (like your expected output suggests) you would have to add the following template to the mix:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*/*/*/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
            <xsl:sort select="@action"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

p.p.s.  the way the `a:matches()` function is written confuses me a little bit. I would do it like this in the last part of the logical expression:

```
(if ($action = 'any') 
    then true()
    else if ($action = 'same')
        then ($target/@action = $src/@action)
        else ($target/@action = $action))
```

it would read: don't care about the `@action` attribute if `any` is asked for, compare the two if `same` is asked for, otherwise assume a certain value was provided so compare to that value. You would then call it with the `same` value in your template:

```
<xsl:for-each-group 
    select="/workorders/*/*/*/*/*[a:matches(current()/parent::*, ., 'same')]/attributes/*" 
    group-by="local-name()">
```